# Getting error "Permissions 0777 for 'myname-2.pem' are too open" while connecting to AWS EC2 instannce

Tags: permissions, chmod, aws

Why connecting to Amazon instance, I got following error:

```
$ ssh -i "myname-2.pem" ec2-user@ec2-12-245-65-0.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
@         WARNING: UNPROTECTED PRIVATE KEY FILE!          @
@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
Permissions 0777 for 'myname-2.pem' are too open.
It is required that your private key files are NOT accessible by others.
This private key will be ignored.
Load key "myname-2.pem": bad permissions
ec2-user@ec2-12-245-65-0.ap-south-1.compute.amazonaws.com: Permission denied (publickey).
```

So I checked the permissions, changed them and rechecked:

```
$ ls -l myname-2.pem 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oem oem 1674 Mar 10 08:13 myname-2.pem
$ sudo chmod 400 myname-2.pem
$ ls -l myname-2.pem 
-rwxrwxrwx 1 oem oem 1674 Mar 10 08:13 myname-2.pem
```

It seems that after running `chmod` the permissions are not getting updated and am not able to connect to EC2 instance. Why is it so?

Comment: Should probably be permissions of `600` or `-rw-------`

Comment: Didnt get. After `sudo chmod 600`, its still `-rwxrwxrwx`

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part of you trying 400.  I wonder if your drive / partition is possibly in a read only status.  Check `mount | grep "/ "`

Comment: Where is this `.pem` file stored? If it's on a USB or network device, then the underlying filesystem could be preventing you from setting the proper permission level 

Answer (score 0):

The same happened to me. After getting the .pem file I moved it to another disk partition. I tried to change permissions but I didnt work. So I tried to move the .pem file to my home directory and changed the permission

```
sudo chmod 400 file-name.pem
```

and it worked.

**This is because NTFS and FAT32 hard drives don't support file permissions on Linux**.